# Number of paths between any two vertices of Kn

Tags: graph-theory

Why the number of paths between any two vertices of K(n) graph is:

[image]

?

Comment: Just like your previous (now deleted) question, you really need to provide some context for this question. Is it homework? If so, what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Can a path repeat vertices?

Comment: The expression you give in the post is for paths that don't repeat vertices.

Comment: @Casteels: I've found this article about Estimating the Number of s-t Paths in a Graph : http://www.maths.uq.edu.au/~kroese/ps/robkro_rev.pdf but it's complicated and I don't know how to proof this formula.

Comment: Ok you should mention that! People around here are happy to help that sort of question, just not so much unmotivated homework problems. Welcome to MSE, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A path can't repeat vertices so if you have a set of the vertices you want to visit then you can know what the path is going to be. Since the path is connected then you can get from any vertex to the other directly, so every permutation of any quantity of vertices contains a path. (of course you cannot pick two of the vertices,namely the one from which you depart and the one where you arrive).

Therefore the number of vertices is the same as the number of permutations out of any number of vertices from 0 to n-2. the number of permutations of k elements out of n-2 is $\dfrac{(n-2)!}{k!}$ but you want the sum for all of the possible values of k (in other words all the possible lengths the path may have)  So you want the sum of all those permutations.

In other words $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\dfrac{(n-2)!}{k!}$.

Mathematicin Srinivasa Ramanujan obtained a result indicating that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\dfrac{(n-2)!}{k!}=\lfloor e(n-2)! \rfloor$

To see why note that $e=1+1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac1{3!}\ldots+\frac{1}{(n-1!)}\ldots$

So $e(n-2)!=(\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}\dfrac{(n-2)!}{k!})+\frac{(n-2)!}{n-1!}+\frac{(n-2)!}{n!}\dots$

But the sum at the end is less than $1$ for $n\geq3$ .(to see why see that the sum at the end is strictly less than the geometrc series $(n-1)+(n-1)^2+(n-1)^3...$ which is exactly 1 when n is 3.